# Ошибка после публикации на сервере IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Опубликовал на сервере IIS  сайт, при запуске выдает ошибку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я понимаю, он не видит файла в этой директории.

Хотя он там есть

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где я не прав?

Comment: Распечатайте точный путь, который генерирует IIS и посмотрите, где на самом деле размещен файл прямым переходом из браузера. Вполне возможно, он указывает не туда и файл лежит в каком-нибудь "~/printers/Printer.Master" с точки зрения сервера.

Comment: Проверьте что Printers помечена в IIS как Application, а не просто как Virtual Folder. правой кнопкой в iis manager по папке - если есть пункт Convert To Application - нажмите.

Comment: Все помогло. Напиши  в ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего папка `Printers` зарегистрирована в IIS как обычный virtual folder, а не как полноценное приложение. Путь `~/Printer.Master` указывает путь относительно корня приложения, так что ASP.NET ищет файл не в `Printers`, а на один логический уровень выше - скорее всего в `c:\inetpub\wwwroot`

Сконвертировать папку в приложение можно в IIS Manager:

- кликнуть правой кнопкой по папке в дереве
- выбрать `Convert To Application`